# Check multiple strings at the same time through list c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, lambda

I have a list which looks like this:

```
ALIBABA - 5 PCS
BAIDU - 4 PCS 
FACEBOOK - 1 PCS
NIO - 2 PCS
```

I was trying to check through that list if it contains specific strings and then get the whole element where the string is. I searched through the web and came across this

```
var newList = listboxitems.Where(x => x.Contains("ALIBABA")).ToList();
```

This outputs me :

```
ALIBABA - 5 PCS
```

How can I search for more elements with more keywords in a one liner ?

Some sort of this ?

```
var newList = listboxitems.Where(x => x.Contains("ALIBABA", "BAIDU")).ToList();
```

So desired output would be :

```
ALIBABA - 5 PCS
BAIDU - 4 PCS
```

Answer (score 3):

Put `"ALIBABA", "BAIDU"` into an array:

`var toCheck = new []{ "ALIBABA", "BAIDU" };`

Then loop the array inside

`listboxitems.Where(x => toCheck.Any(check => x.Contains(check)))`

Unfortunately, because you are doing a `Contains` you cannot speed this up with a `HashSet`

Answer (score 0):

`you can create a list of keywords`

```
string[] keyword = { "ALIBABA", "Don Box" };
var newList = listboxitems.Where(x => keyword.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: OP wants to check whether `x` contains the keyword anywhere, this doesn't do that